# windows server 2016 The system failed to register host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRs) for network adapter

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

hi i have recently started using windows server 2016. Every 15 minutes the server seems to reboot with windows kernel power critical id 41 error. Just before the system reboots I receive a Microsoft-Windows-DNS client Events Error

```
The system failed to register host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRs) for 
network adapter
with settings:

       Adapter Name : {}
       Host Name : 
       Primary Domain Suffix : 
       DNS server list :

       Sent update to server : <?>
       IP Address(es) :


 The reason the system could not register these RRs was because of a 
 security related problem. The cause of this could be (a) your computer does 
 not have permissions to register and update the specific DNS domain name 
 set for this adapter, or (b) there might have been a problem negotiating 
 valid credentials with the DNS server during the processing of the update 
 request.

 You can manually retry DNS registration of the network adapter and its 
 settings by typing 'ipconfig /registerdns' at the command prompt. If 
 problems still persist, contact your DNS server or network systems 
 administrator. See event details for specific error code information.
```

Why would this happen i have not changed anything

Comment: That error is simply the system acknowledging it wasn't shut down (or restarted) cleanly. It gives no info about what actually caused the shutdown. Please provide more information.

Comment: Look at this topic, looks like here is the similar issue, but with desktop OS. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/computer-constantly-goes-into-endless-reboot-and/ec945b13-d63f-4730-9b60-2e3b55f8c777

Comment: Possible duplicate (no answer yet): https://serverfault.com/questions/849909/kernel-power-event-every-15-minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Server Reboot in your case is not related to the issue of the DNS registration. While I cannot conclude why the server restarts in your case, you can eliminate the cause of the DNS registration failure error.

Just turn off the checkbox “Register this connection's addresses in DNS” in “Advanced TCP/IP Settings” dialog, “DNS” tab.

To open this dialog, go to the Control Panel, “Network and Sharing Center”, click “Manage network connections”, right-click on your network connection. Then, from the pop-up menu, select “Properties” item, select “Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)” and click the “Properties” button.

This checkbox specifies that the computer attempt dynamic registration of the IP addresses (through DNS) of this connection with the full computer name of this computer, as specified on the “Computer Name” tab (available in System in Control Panel). The local setting is used only if the associated Group Policy is disabled or unspecified.

Please refer to the following links for further reading:

- https://support.simpledns.plus/kb/a3/system-failed-to-register-host-resource-records-rrs-network-adapter___-warning-windows-event-log.aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754143.aspx

Comment: hi thanks the system restart was caused by issue at the web host therefore it was unrelated

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues registering DNS due to permission issue. Often, a machine first gets an IP from DHCP before the IP is changed to static. In a default configuration DHCP creates the DNS entry, and the DHCP server's computer account is listed as the Owner. In this case the client machine's computer account has no permission to change the DNS entry unless you have DHCP and DNS set up to allow it. When you run ipconfig /registerDNS from the client machine it fill fail because of this, and you will find this in your event log. The easy fix is to delete the DHCP server owned DNS entry, then run ipconfig /registerDNS from the client machine again. This allows the machine to create a new record with itself as the owner.

A longer term fix will require you to learn more about Windows DNS so you can configure DHCP/DNS in the best manner for your environment.