# Kernel-Power event every 15 minutes

Tags: windows-event-log, windows-update, windows-server-2016, server-crashes

Been having an issue since about 12 hours ago on our `Windows Server 2016` instance:
[image]

Note the time pattern - every ~2 minutes, then every ~15 minutes. It's been doing this without fail. If I'm RDP'd in at the time, the connection will be lost, but very quickly after that it'll be back with the `Shutdown Event Tracker` dialog and all applications/etc closed. It feels way quicker than a full reboot which is extremely odd to me.

It's a virtual machine. I've asked the hosting company to run diagnostics on the physical environment to see if there might be an issue there.

This is a new server and has been online and stable for about a month. Two days ago I installed a Windows Update (I can edit this post with further info about which updates) which required a restart for the first time since this server was installed.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what this might be?

Driving me up the wall this is.

Comment: We wouldn't have the first clue as to why this is happening based on the information you provided. The Event ID in your screen shot is an event that occurs **after** the server crashes. What does the detailed text in these events say? What else is in the System event log? We need more details from you.

Comment: @joeqwerty, I realise that now. I just thought that time pattern was going to be familiar to someone.

Comment: @joeqwerty I've exported the event log and am analyzing it on my local machine. Honestly it would just be too much to share (even if I filter down to just Error and Critical). I wouldn't know what details are pertinent. There are definitely patterns and recurring events with each crash. Whether they happen before or after the actual cause of the issue, I wouldn't know.

Comment: Look for Error and Critical events from the System event log for one of the time periods  that correlate to the Kernel Power events. That should help you narrow it down and simplify the search.

Comment: @joeqwerty, there's a plot twist - it hasn't crashed in 1 hour (after crashing consistently 6/7 times per hour for 16 hours). This soon after asking the hosting provider to check the physical environment, and them coming back to me and saying that it's fine. Anyway thanks for that tip. It's what I've been doing, and I see nothing glaring - to my [non-sysadmin] mind it's a hardware failure.